# Is there a way to get Firefox to work with macOS keychain? If not, is there a good alternative password manager?

Tags: forms, macos, firefox, passwords

If so, how? If not, I am looking for a password manager that can do at least the following:

- works offline even if the service is down, such that data is stored locally (KEY!) I want to retain full access and control.
- securely stores notes, either to a website or general notes
- has an effective form filler
- syncs with other devices
- uses end-to-end encryption
- ideally works well with Firefox on macOS

I am aware of popular ones like LastPass, 1Password, and Dashlane. I haven't worked through all the details yet but I'm concerned with some of the breaches, some repeated, and periods of unavailability.

I have also used Roboform on Windows many years ago. I REALLY liked it because it could handle almost any type of sign-on scenario and forms with grace... but that was then. I've read they have since gone downhill.

So, ultimately, I am looking for recommendations from users with personal, hands-on experience as to which ones are easy to work with and capable. I need to manage hundreds of sign-ons, forms, etc.

Comment: I’ve switched from 1Password to Bitwarden. It’s cheap and works well.